# google+ share via url - choosing account by parameter

Tags: google-plus, share

I'm encountering the problem with sharing the content of my company's blog with company's google+ account. When I press the sharing button it opens a new window which url has got only one parameter, namly url of shared content page. Is there any way to send as the other parameter the name/id of the google profile? How would be the name of that parameter? And what should be the value of it? Would that be the same string as the last string in url of company's google+ profile?

Any help appreciated. Best regards,
Jarek

Comment: your going to have to be logged into the companies google+ account to share it.

Comment: But there's no way to log into company profile as it was the user. I can log in to the profile that is the owner of company page or a manager and then switch to company's profile. After that the logo in the top right corner changes to company, but when I'm trying to share anything I am still seen as the private user, who is logged on.